# Cloning an implemented abstract method

Tags: java, abstract-methods

I'm a beginner in Java and I wanted to ask a question:

Is that possible to clone implemented abstract method body?

Example:

```
public abstract class ClassA{
  public abstract void method();
}

ClassA objA = new ClassA(){
  public void method(){
    System.out.println("Yay");
  }
}

//creating objB with the same method as in objA

objB.method();
```

```
Output: Yay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just implement `Cloneable` interface to `ClassA` class.

```
public abstract class ClassA implements Cloneable {
    public abstract void method();
    @Override
    public ClassA clone() {
        try {
            return (ClassA) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this.

```
ClassA objB = objA.clone();
objB.method();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an implementation of the abstract class `ClassA`:

```java
public class ClassAImpl extends ClassA {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Yay");
    }
}
```

Then you can create the instances `objA` and `objB`:

```java
public class ExampleClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassAImpl objA = new ClassAImpl();
        objA.method();
        ClassAImpl objB = new ClassAImpl();
        objB.method();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Yay
Yay
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks good and easy. However this still requires to create an extra class which may be impossible in some situations for me. But still nice explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        ClassA objB = objA.getClass().newInstance();
        objB.method();
```

No Cloneable needed.